# 2 Unidentified Printed Pieces, 2x3 Dark Grey Slope and Black 2x2 Tile

Tags: set-identification

Below I attached two photos. I am not sure if they are from the same set or not. I was wondering what set(s) they are in.

[image: Part 1 (2x3 gray) It isn't light gray, it is strange shade.]

[image: Part 2(2x2 black tile)]

Comment: Sorry for the bad quality, phone camera is meh, and only selfie camera works.

Comment: Can you describe the piece in words? Is it a lego brick with studs on top, a lego tile with a flat surface on top, a sloped piece, etc? How many studs by how many studs is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slope piece is [Slope 33 3 x 2 with Insectoid Scope Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3298pb005&idColor=10) from [9 (or 10) Insectoid sets from 1998-99](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3298pb005&in=S).

[image: slope piece]

The 2 x 2 tile is [Tile 2 x 2 with Insectoid Logo in Triangle Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068bpx7&idColor=11) from [9 (or 10) mostly-Insectoids sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bpx7&in=S).

[image: tile piece]

There are a few sets with both pieces.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I looked at the five that had both of them, and I think it is cosmic creeper. Thanks for your help I have all if those neon and green pieces as well, but realized I must have another set because I still have some unused neon pieces.